# Creating My Own Document Viewer

Tags: java, javascript, document-view

I want to create a File Viewer with Java Servlets and JavaScript. I'm hosting various document formats in my server, i want to provide viewing option for the files through browser. I want to support MS Docs, Open office Docs,PDF Files,Text Files, etc. I have been using Zoho Viewer, which is going to be discontinued. So i would like to start on creating my own File Viewer.(I'm planning to provide edit option also like Google Docs). Hope i have to use XML Schemas for opening different binary documents (ex :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Word_XML_Format_example).
Can someone point me in the right direction to start with ..?

P.S : I have Googled and 'Stackd' but i couldn't find any useful hints to begin. That's why i'm posting this question. I know there is already a question for Doc Viewer in StackOverFlow, but it's about viewing file as a Flash Content, i want to view files as HTML Content/

Comment: You may want to check out [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/index.html) for various MS document formats support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use/adapt tools like [LibreOffice Sdk](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/) or [OpenOffice SDK](http://www.openoffice.org/development/)

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe start by looking at the code in a WYSIWYG editor like FCKEditor. Don't use anyone else's code unless the license is compatible with your project's license.